# get the raw and parsed payloads from aws api gateway inside the event?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, slack-api, serverless

I am trying to validate slack the requests on events that I receive on my lambda, I'm currently using api-gateway with a lambda backend.

On my serverless.yml I have this for my event handler

```
          integration: lambda
          passthroughBehavior: "WHEN_NO_TEMPLATE"
          request:
              template:
                application/x-www-form-urlencoded: ${file(aws-api-gateway-form-to-json.ftl)}
```

I got the contents for the file generated through the AWS API Proxy's Console, I'm using the generated method request passthrough with *one modification* which is just adding the raw body to the payload to be delivered to the lambda `"rawBody": "$input.body",`, however when I add this modification the requests stop arriving to the lambda and I get errors when I send requests.

```
##  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html
##  This template will pass through all parameters including path, querystring, header, stage variables, and context through to the integration endpoint via the body/payload
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
"body-json" : $input.json('$'),
"rawBody": "$input.body",
"params" : {
#foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
"$type" : {
    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
    "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
}
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"stage-variables" : {
#foreach($key in $stageVariables.keySet())
"$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($stageVariables.get($key))"
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"context" : {
    "account-id" : "$context.identity.accountId",
    "api-id" : "$context.apiId",
    "api-key" : "$context.identity.apiKey",
    "authorizer-principal-id" : "$context.authorizer.principalId",
    "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
    "cognito-authentication-provider" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider",
    "cognito-authentication-type" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType",
    "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId",
    "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId",
    "http-method" : "$context.httpMethod",
    "stage" : "$context.stage",
    "source-ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp",
    "user" : "$context.identity.user",
    "user-agent" : "$context.identity.userAgent",
    "user-arn" : "$context.identity.userArn",
    "request-id" : "$context.requestId",
    "resource-id" : "$context.resourceId",
    "resource-path" : "$context.resourcePath"
    }
}
```

---

To answer some of the feedback.
If I use the `Use Lambda Proxy integration` in the `Integration Request`
I get a payload like this, which is great, but I also need the rawbody which isn't present.

```
{ body: 
{ token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
team_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
api_app_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
event: 
{ client_msg_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
type: 'message',
text: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
user: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
ts: '123456789.000200',
channel: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
event_ts: '123456789.000200',
channel_type: 'im' },
type: 'event_callback',
event_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
event_time: 123456798,
authed_users: [ 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' ] },
method: 'POST',
principalId: '',
stage: 'dev',
cognitoPoolClaims: { sub: '' },
enhancedAuthContext: {},
headers: 
{ Accept: '*/*',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
'CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto': 'https',
'CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer': 'true',
'CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer': 'false',
'CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer': 'false',
'CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer': 'false',
'CloudFront-Viewer-Country': 'US',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
Host: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com',
'User-Agent': 'Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)',
Via: '1.1 xxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx==',
'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=xxxxxxxxxxxx',
'X-Forwarded-For': 'xx.xx.xx.xx, xx.xx.xx.xx',
'X-Forwarded-Port': '443',
'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https',
'X-Slack-Request-Timestamp': '12345678',
'X-Slack-Signature': 'v0=xxxxxxxxxxxx' },
query: {},
path: {},
identity: 
{ cognitoIdentityPoolId: '',
accountId: '',
cognitoIdentityId: '',
caller: '',
sourceIp: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
accessKey: '',
cognitoAuthenticationType: '',
cognitoAuthenticationProvider: '',
userArn: '',
userAgent: 'Slackbot 1.0 (+https://api.slack.com/robots)',
user: '' },
stageVariables: {} }
```

Comment: To clarify some of the things that I ran into, in case they help anyone else, the raw payload was plain json, I only need to parse the string to json and then stringify it back, that helped me solve the biggest issue I was running into.

In the end I didn't need the custom templates, the provided lambda proxy was enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in Serverless there's a few integration options here. https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#request-templates

To clarify, you are using `lambda` so you are then on the hook for manually defining your template in API Gateway (which you provided).

When you try to have your `serverless.yml` use the `lambda-proxy` (alternatively accepted as `aws-proxy` or `aws_proxy`), you're saying you got everything sent to you in a different format that did not include the raw body.

*Side note: In terms of API Gateway's `LAMBDA_PROXY` integration, you should get the full request body. It is the integration I use all the time (along with `ANY` method on a `{proxy+}` request path) to specifically avoid mapping templates. I'm not sure if Serverless framework ends up doing additional parsing on the `event`, but you should indeed have the entire body in the event given to the Lambda function handler. I've written a framework for AWS serverless and it is what I use there and I do handle request formats other than JSON. So I know you can get the "raw" body. Do you need to use a framework in this case?*

Ok, so my understanding is that you can't work with the `lambda-proxy` integration and must resort to the custom mapping in API Gateway.

I'd honestly need to see some of the errors from CloudWatch. I'd also want to see some example request body examples you're expecting to receive. You said there's errors, but didn't post anything about them. My assumption is that it's a template issue in API Gateway. It has been some time since I worked in detail with the mappings (again, the `LAMBDA_PROXY` integration is the way to go), but let me throw out some ideas.

Remember that `$input.body` *could* include JSON that could mess up the template. That would create an error and your Lambda would never be triggered. In CloudWatch, you'd see things about being unable to parse things.

You *could* try the `$util.escapeJavaScript()` function. You *could* try the trick of using the `$util.base64Decode()` function as well (this requires enabling binary support on your API).

API Gateway can work with binary data, represented as base64 strings, and that is one way to not get into trouble with the template mapping stuff. Then, for example `"rawBody": "$util.base64Decode($input.body)"` would work in your mapping template.

To enable binary support, go to the API Gateway API's settings and you'll see a section for `Binary Media Types`. You can provide whichever content type string you want there, even `application/json` if you really wanted. I think if you are accepting JSON, you probably could be fine parsing it (potentially along with escaping)...But if you are getting stuck with something weird, you may need to do this. Though keep in mind, it's an API wide setting. I think from the looks of what you shared, you'd just be using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` here, so normal JSON requests would be unaffected for example.

Bottom line is that there's a parsing error somewhere.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, I've been busy with another project and couldn't go back to this sooner.


As for the errors, I don't actually see any errors on Cloudwatch on the lambda (the request just never arrives there), I was never able to figure out where on the api gateway I can enable logging.


The request is a post using application/x-www-form-urlencoded, another a header with a signature (which is a signed version of the raw payload, headers and all), and the form encoded body, I'll try to pull an example.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how serverless works, my workflow is limited to writing code locally and uploading zips, and any other configuration is done on the AWS Consolse itself.

I believe what you're looking for a little feature called [Lambda Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html), you'll find it under the Integration Request tab on the API Gateway. What it does is, it provides two standard mapping templates for  both Request and Response.

When you use Lambda Proxy Integration, your event object will look something like this:

```
{
  "resource": "/users/single",
  "path": "/users/single",
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "Host": "xxxxxxx.execute-api.xxxx.amazonaws.com",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "X-Forwarded-For": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
    "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
    "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
  },
  "multiValueHeaders": {
    "accept": [
      "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
    ],
    "accept-encoding": ["gzip, deflate, br"],
    "accept-language": ["en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"],
    "Host": ["xxxxx.execute-api.xxxx.amazonaws.com"],
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": ["1"],
    "User-Agent": [
      "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
    ],
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": ["Root=xxxxx"],
    "X-Forwarded-For": ["xx.xx.xx.xx"],
    "X-Forwarded-Port": ["443"],
    "X-Forwarded-Proto": ["https"]
  },
  // this contains the get body
  "queryStringParameters": { "id": "2" },
  "multiValueQueryStringParameters": { "id": ["2"] },
  // This contains pathParams, if you url looks like users/{id}, this object will contain a key called id containing the value from the URL
  "pathParameters": null,
  "stageVariables": null,
  "requestContext": {
    "resourceId": "xxxxx",
    "resourcePath": "/users/single",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "extendedRequestId": "xxxxxxx=",
    "requestTime": "xx/xx/xxxx:xx:xx:xx +0000",
    "path": "/dev/users/single",
    "accountId": "642495909037",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "stage": "dev",
    "domainPrefix": "xxxxx",
    "requestTimeEpoch": 1547113372715,
    "requestId": "xx-xx-xx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
    "identity": {
      "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
      "accountId": null,
      "cognitoIdentityId": null,
      "caller": null,
      "sourceIp": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
      "accessKey": null,
      "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
      "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
      "userArn": null,
      "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
      "user": null
    },
    "domainName": "xxxxxxx.execute-api.xxxxxxx.amazonaws.com",
    "apiId": "xxxx"
  },
  "body": null, //this contains the post body
  "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

The "body" key is always string, you have to parse it according to the content-type i.e. json or www-form-encoded or whatever else.

When using Lambda Proxy the object you return from your handler **has** to follow a specific format according to which API Gateway maps it back to the response, which is:

```
{
    statusCode: Integer,
    headers: HashTable<String, String>,
    body: String
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am indeed using the Proxy Integration, serverless just automates that part.
The template I added is the one I'm using to parse the events, if I just use the amazon generated one, it will work, but according to the documentation, $input.body should contain the raw request, when I add it to the template, it doesn't work, what you posted, is the body of the parsed request, my trouble is with the parser template.

Comment: As far as I understand, the parsing happens between API Gateway and Lambda.

So, the Apache Velocity code snippet you posted runs on the raw HTTP Request, converts it into an Object or HashMap or Dictionary and then passes it to the function's event variable. If you use proxy integration, you don't need to add a mapping template yourself, aws does that for you.

Now if you don't have it enabled, then you can **manually** add a mapping template to parse only the required details into a formatted JSON of your choice from the HTTP Request body, which is written in Apache Velocity.

Comment: If I don't use a custom mapping template it only delivers a json parsed body, but I don't get access to the raw payload, which prevents me from validating the request.

Comment: Lambda Proxy always sends body as a raw unparsed string. Maybe turn off the extra mapping template, then log and inspect the event object and see what it contains.

Comment: I only added the mapping template because I wasn't getting the raw unparsed string.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, but a year and a half later I still had this issue, and I found many other similar SO posts, so here's what works in Dec 2020:

The default API Gateway setting is to treat inputs as text, and to serialize them to JSON.  This causes issues with inputs that are not text, e.g. multipart/form-data with image/jpeg.  The best way to get around this is to enable API gateway binary media types for the Content-Type that you expect to be binary data (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html).  This will cause API Gateway to hand over to Lambda a base64 encoded value for body instead of trying to serialize to JSON (it also sets the 'isBase64Encoded' header).  This way, you can use the Lambda Proxy Integration and not have to mess around with mapping templates or any of the `$util.escapeJavaScript()` madness.  The only change to deal with in the Lambda code is to base64decode the body.